# Multivariate quantile regression group lasso in R

Tags: r, lasso, quantile-regression, multivariate-regression

I'm trying to fit a multivariate sparse quantile regression model with group lasso. The regression is multivariate as there are several dependent variables, $Y=(y_1,\dots,y_k)$. The selected $X$s must be the same in each equation (for each component of $Y$).

I know this is possible in classical regression with `glmnet` using Multiresponse Gaussian Family:

```
#data
d = 20
n = 500
X = matrix(runif(n*d, min = -2, max = 2), ncol = d, nrow = n)

feature_n = 8 #number of true predictors
feature_index = sort(sample(seq_len(d), feature_n, replace = FALSE))

p = 5 #number of Y
beta = matrix(0, ncol = d, nrow = p)
beta[,feature_index] = matrix(runif(p*feature_n, min = -1, max = 1),
                              ncol = feature_n, nrow = p)

e = matrix(rnorm(p*n, sd = 0.3), ncol = p, nrow = n) #error term

Y = X %*% t(beta) + e

#fit with glmnet
library(glmnet)
cvmfit = cv.glmnet(X, Y, family = "mgaussian")
mfit_cv = glmnet(X, Y, family = "mgaussian", lambda = cvmfit$lambda.1se)
coef(mfit_cv)
```

Does anyone know a package or can give me a tip on how to do it for quantile regression?

Comment: Looks like the [`rqPen`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rqPen/index.html) package has the functionality for the case of a univariate dependent variable. Try the function [`rq.group.fit`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rqPen/versions/2.2.2/topics/rq.group.fit). Not sure about a multivariate dependent variable.

Comment: (I have edited the question based on the comments to a now deleted answer.)

Comment: Thank you @RichardHardy for this edit which is clearer. I hope someone else have a solution...